# Stacking and adding up numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack

I have an array `g`.

```
g = np.array([])
```

I have some loops through which I need to build it with the following structure in python:

```
[
[1 4 
 2 5 
 3 6]
[7 10
 8 11
 9 12]
]
...
```

i.e. any number of rows (let's say 10), but with each entry consisting of a 3x2 array.

After initializing `g` at the top, I'm doing this:

```
       curr_g = np.array([])
       for y, w in zip(z.T, weights.T):
            temp_g = sm.WLS(y, X, w).fit()
            # temp_g.params produces a (3L,) array
            # curr_g is where I plan to end up with a 3x2 array
            curr_g = np.hstack((temp_g.params, curr_g))

        g = np.hstack((temp_g.params, g))
```

I thought that when I use `hstack` with two 3x1 arrays, then I'll end up with one single 3x2 array. But what's happening is that after the stacking, `curr_g` just goes from `(3L,)` to `(6L,)`...

Also, once I've got a 3x2 array, how do I stack 3x2 arrays on top of each other?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct saying that "when I use hstack with two 3x1 arrays, then I'll end up with one single 3x2 array":

```
params =array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)
curr_g =array([4,5,6]).reshape(3,1)
print hstack((params, curr_g)).shape  # == (3,2)
```

Likely, you get an array with shape `(6,)` because `temp_g.params` and `g` have both shape `(3,)`, not `(3,1)`. If this is the case, you're better of with `column_stack((temp_g.params, curr_g))`.

To the last point, you first initialize your big array `g` to the right size:

```
g=array((N,3,2))
```

and then you fill it in the for loop:

```
for j, (y, w) in enumerate(zip(z.T, weights.T)):
    #calculate temp_g and curr_g
    g[j]=column_stack((temp_g.params, curr_g))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work... I print out curr_g's shape it's: (0L), and I get the error: `return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)...
   ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: Can you post `temp_g.params.shape` and `curr_g.shape`?

Comment: temp_g.params is (3L,) and curr_g.shape is (0L,). But what I've tried now is to initialize curr_g like this this  
`curr_g = np.array([3,])`. Then in the loop I say:  
                 `if curr_g is None:  curr_g = np.c_[temp_g.params, curr_g]  else: curr_g = temp_g.params`
In this case, `curr_g` does end up with `(3L,)`, but it doesn't stack up alright. I wanted it to get assigned `temp_g` only when it's empty, but it seems to be doing the reverse... and it only holds the current value of `temp_g`, but doesn't stack up with the previous value.

Comment: The problem is in how you calculate `curr_g` then, and not on how to stack the arrays together.

Comment: I don't calculate `curr_g`. When it's empty I need to simply assign it the value of `temp_g`, and when it's not empty, and it already holds the previous `temp_g`, I need to stack the new `temp_g` onto it. `temp_g` is always calculated to comes out as (3L,)

Comment: if `temp_g` is an array with size `(3,)`, you will end up with an array with size `(N,3)`, not `(N,3,2)` as you show above.

Comment: I see. Then what should I do to force it to be (3,1)? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: you can reshape it to `(3,1)` with `temp_g = temp_g.reshape(3,1)`, but you will end up with a final array with size `(N,3,1)`, not `(N,3,2)`.

Comment: so is this task impossible?